# How to recenter an easymodal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I'd like to recenter an [easymodal](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/easyModal.js/) modal with JS. The modal object is created with the following code:

```
modal = new ModalMarkus('#create_annotation_dialog');

//here's the definition of ModalMarkus in another file
function ModalMarkus(elem) {
  this.modal_dialog = jQuery(elem).easyModal({
    updateZIndexOnOpen: false
  });
}
```

Here's the HTML of `create_annotation_dialog`:

```
  <aside class='dialog' id='create_annotation_dialog'> 
      <div>
        <div style="float: left;">
          <p>
            <textarea id='new_annotation_content' onkeyup="updateAnnotationPreview()"></textarea>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right">
          <p>
          <h2 id="annotation_preview_title" style="display: none"> <%= t('marker.annotation.preview_title') %></h2>
          </p>
          <p id="annotation_preview" style="display: none; word-wrap: break-word;"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </aside>
```

What I'd like to do is recenter the modal dialog when I change the visibility of `annotation_preview` and `annotation_preview_title`. I have two functions as shown below and I'd like for them to reposition the modal to the center of the screen.

```
function hideAnnotationPreview(){
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview").hide();
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview_title").hide();
}

function showAnnotationPreview(){
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview").show();
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview_title").show();
}
```

The modal is centered when it's opened but I change the visibility of items within the modal which results in the following:
[image: off-center modal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's how I modified those functions:

```
function hideAnnotationPreview(){
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview").hide();
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview_title").hide();
    var dialog = jQuery("#create_annotation_dialog");
    dialog.css("margin-left", -1 * dialog.width() / 2);
}

function showAnnotationPreview(){
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview").show();
    document.getElementById("annotation_preview_title").show();
    var dialog = jQuery("#create_annotation_dialog");
    dialog.css("margin-left", -1 * dialog.width() / 2);
}
```